# Set :selected value based on variableX -or- the user submitted value if variableX is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, submit, default-value

Have this select dropdown input field that is populated with state names.

*I want to set the selected value to be the content of @state.id if this is not nil. If there is already a chosen option then I would like that to be selected instead.*

How can this be done correctly? I tried several solution all of which fails, latest code example im using now:

```
    = p.input :state,
              :collection => ["State1","State2"]
              :selected => (@state.id.to_s rescue nil) || (params[:state] rescue nil),
              :id => "state",
              :name => "state",
              :prompt => t('forms.choose')
```

Comment: there's a typo in the line `:collection => ["State1","State2"}` I didn't understand your question. Do you want this select to be choosen according to another input or based on the alredy chosen option of the object ?

Comment: Fixed typo I want to set the selected value to be the content of @state.id if this is not nil. If there is already a chosen option then I would like that to be selected instead.

Comment: There's another type :) It's missing a comma after the collection array.
Is there any error? or It's just prompting the wrong value? Please have a look on my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the :selected option works based on two values.

1. The index of the element in the collection array, or
2. The value itself

So lets say you want the the last option to be selected, in your case you would need:

```
:selected => 1
```

or

```
:selected => "State2"
```

I hope it helps.